# Install nvidia-opengl headers in ubuntu

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, driver, nvidia

I've been struggling with setting up opengl in ubuntu.

My glxinfo:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 9.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
```

I have a nvidia GT 520m card, how can I use opengl library by nvidia? I installed *nvidia-current* and *nvidia-current-dev*, but nothing happens. I need a newer version of opengl but it seems my intel integrated card only supports opengl 2.1.

My laptop:

Acer 4743g; 2g ddr3 memory; gt 520m graphics card.

Comment: Sounds like an [Optimus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus#Linux_support) problem.

Comment: All the graphics cards use optimus technology, do all of them have the same problem? I installed bumblebee to accommodate optimus, but nothing more happened. Everytime I ran optirun to run a program, it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers tab

Select the NVIDIA one and reboot